# ASP.NET Core : Passing Relevant Data to a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Working from the 2017 ASP.Net Core Microsoft Contoso University example I am displaying data about a Coach in my main parent view. I want the partial view to be a form for submitting a review of that chosen teacher (Database is ready for this). The partial page needs CoachID in this e.g.

What is a good practice to be able to send CoachModel data to my Partialview that is using ReviewModel? If I also wanted to send related data about students, then how would that go about?

My main goal is to create a review of a coach, i need studentID and target CoachID.

If it is relevant : a coach can have many reviews and a student can make many reviews about coaches.

Edit: Suggestions for relevant elements in my partial is greatly appreciated! And no i am not very experienced.

Parent View

```
@model Models.Coach

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <h4>Coach</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Methodology)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Methodology)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AverageRating)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reviews)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Reviews.Count)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
   //How can i pass in "CoachID"
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/CreateReview.cshtml", new GolfCoachDB.Models.Review())
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.CoachID">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

And my Partial:

```
@model Models.Review

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Reviews</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CoachID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CoachID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CoachID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rating" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a `<select>` element for `CoachId`? And you can just use `@Html.Partial("..", new Review( { CoachId = Model.CoachID })`

Comment: I do not want <select> element. It is just example code from a already existing page. I will edit my OP to specify this...

Comment: Note also `<dl>` (_Definition List_) elements are not appropriate for your html

Comment: What elements do you think would be approppriate in this case @Stephen Muecke ? Thanks for your answers and time...

Comment: Just `<span>` and `<div>` elements (and your already using bootstrap, so you can use its grid system for the layout if you want)

Comment: The ideal practice is to create a view that represents your data, so if your domain object doesn't handle both items reflected on your page, i.e. to separate domain objects you would create a Model-View-View-Model to act as a wrapper, so one model can interact with both your main and partial rendered via a parameter.